# Set Theory Proofs - Proving the First Distributive Identity

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

My book's explanation for the proof for the first distributive identity, that A ∪ (B ∩ C) =  (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C) makes little sense to me after the third line. I don't understand how this is viable as it sort of is "self reference" on the forth line. To get from the third statement to the next, the **distributive law** would need to be applied, or so it seems.

x ∈ A ∪ (B ∩ C) ≡

(x ∈ A) ∨ (x ∈ (B ∩ C)) ≡

(x ∈ A) ∨ (x ∈ B ∧ x ∈ C) ≡

(x ∈ A ∨ x ∈B) ∧ (x ∈ A ∨ x ∈ C) ≡

x ∈ (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C)

This is from Discrete Math by Kenneth Rosen...

Comment: If we write $P, Q, R$ instead of $x\in A, x\in B, x\in C$, then the third and fourth line says:
$$
P\lor (Q\land R)\\
(P\lor Q)\land (P\lor R)
$$
which, for instance, can be confirmed equivalent via a truth table.

Comment: Yes, it's some kind of distributivity but on logical operators rather than set operators.

Comment: drawing a venn diagram helped me understand it